# Как написали ОС и первый компилятор?

Tags: история

Сейчас, чтобы написать программу, мы включаем компьютер, который грузит операционную систему, в которой мы открываем IDE, пишем код и компилируем его в уже готовом компиляторе.
А как создали первый компилятор или же саму ОС, без ОС и компиляторов?
Когда писали компилятор ассемблер, использовали чисто машинные коды. В какой среде (интерфейсе) это было сделано?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80#%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Паяльником соединяли пересечения на сетке проводов.

Comment: Писать на ассемблере можно и без компилятора: берем листочек, пишем программу, вручную переводим в машинные коды, машинные коды переносим на носитель информации (перфоленту, перфокарту), либо физическими перемычками "по живому" программируем "ПЗУ".